Discord.py MyClient(Commands.Bot) and commands.Greedy
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html#greedy
I am following a tutorial that creates a child object of commands.bot in order to run a background task.
I am attempting to implement the discord.ext.commands.Greedy on a slash command in order to pass a list of discord.Member objects to be operated on.
I am recieving the given error on startup TypeError: unsupported type annotation Greedy[Member] 
example code to replicate my error
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands

class MyClient(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self, *, intents: discord.Intents):
        super().__init__(command_prefix="/", intents=intents)

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
intents.members = True

client = MyClient(intents=intents)

@client.tree.command(name="slap")
async def slap(interaction: discord.Interaction, members: discord.ext.commands.Greedy[discord.Member], *, reason='no reason'):
    slapped = ", ".join(x.name for x in members)
    await interaction.response.send_message(f'{slapped} just got slapped for {reason}')

I am on discord.py version 2.4
how would I fix the sample code to have a slash command run with more than one discord.Member and output the given text.
a working command should look like
/slap members:@user1, @user2, @user3 reason="I am greedy"

It's just not possible

@ŁukaszKwieciński That is very unfortunate if true

Possible duplicate

This question is similar to: AppCommand get endless parameters. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Try using mention.
slapped = ", ".join(member.mention for member in members)

